# How do I change my direction towards rotation angle at all times?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have this script below and I want my player to always move towards the rotation angle, which doesn't happen. It only changes direction when I click.

My purpose is for the player to move at all times and towards the rotation which should be controlled by mouse position/mouse x axis (kind of like auto-run, but always change rotation based on mouse, not just move right or left).

I've tried about 10 different methods, nothing worked so far...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 4;
public float rot = 0f;
public float rotSpeed = 80;
public float gravity = 8;

private Camera cam;
Vector3 moveDir = Vector3.zero;

CharacterController controller;
Animator anim;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
           
 
 float horizontalSpeed = 8.0f;
 //Get the mouse delta. This is not in the range -1...1
 float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
 float z = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
 transform.Rotate(0, h, 0);

  //Move Input
    
  if(controller.isGrounded){
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
  {
            
    
   anim.SetInteger ("condition", 1);
   moveDir = new Vector3 (0,0,1) * speed;

   // moveDir *= speed;
   moveDir = transform.TransformDirection(moveDir);

            
    }

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
    {
    anim.SetInteger("condition", 0);
    moveDir = Vector3.zero;
    }

    
    }

   

    moveDir.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

}

Comment: simply look at !

Answer (score 0):

[Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)
Just get a cursor position and that's it

Comment: Is not really working.   
Maybe I did it wrong, transform.LookAt what exactly?
I've tried to make a ray to take the mouse position, I cannot look at input.mouseposition only on the x axis, so it just rotates my plaer on the wrong axis and never moves. 
I cannot change the ```moveDir``` vector to anything useful...

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 direction = target.position - player.transform.position;
Quaternion finalPlayerRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
player.transform.rotation = finalPlayerRotation;
```

This also works in some cases:

```
Vector3 direction = target.position - player.transform.position;
player.transform.right /*You may need to change the Right to upper, -upper, -Right depend on the player rotation and the target position*/ = direction;
```